# Strapi v4 api error "posts.map is not a function" NextJs

Tags: api, next.js, blogs, strapi

index.js file

```
export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts &&
        posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <h2>{post.Title}</h2>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

and this is the error that appears to me "TypeError: posts.map is not a function"
Any idea about it?

Comment: If you `console.log(posts)` in your `getStaticProps()` function, can you confirm that it's an array?

Comment: oh nooo it's not
this is what it shows me
{
  data: [
    { id: 1, attributes: [Object] },
    { id: 2, attributes: [Object] },
    { id: 3, attributes: [Object] },
    { id: 4, attributes: [Object] }
  ],
  meta: { pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, total: 4 } }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posts` is an object — the array of posts you want to call `map` on is assigned to `posts.data`:

```js
export default function Home({ posts }) {
  const { data } = posts; // unpack `data` from `posts`

  // call `map()` on `data`
  return (
    <div>
      {data && data.length
        ? data.map((post) => (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <h2>{post.attributes.Title}</h2>
            </div>
          ))
        : "no posts"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yea and how can I access the Title please?

Comment: This is the stracture
{
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"attributes": {
"Title": "Hello everyone",
"Slug": "hello-everyone",
"Content": "HSASUAKDQVFVJQVFVFQJFB",
"createdAt": "2022-04-17T17:51:20.265Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-04-17T17:51:22.528Z",
"publishedAt": "2022-04-17T17:51:22.524Z"
}
},
}

Comment: @YacineAyechi You'd access it by using `post.attributes.Title`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks for you help <3